# WordPress Default Featured Image

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I’ve got a WordPress site and have added the following code to the Single.php file, which means if I publish a blog post without selecting a ‘Featured Image’, it will display a default ‘Featuered Image’ instead (tellymedia-temporary-image.jpg).

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
} else { ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/branding/tellymedia-temporary-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

This works fine on the actual page displaying the individual blog post (which shows the default image), but I’m also using the following code in my Functions.php file, to display a ‘Featured Image’ thumbnail for each post in the Sidebar:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="widget-listing-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></span><?php get_the_title() ? the_title()+the_subtitle('<span class="widget-subtitle">', '</span class="widget-subtitle">') : the_ID(); ?></a>
```

While this works for all other posts it doesn’t work for any where I haven’t selected a ‘Featued Image’. Is there a way to tweak the code in my Functions.php file please, so it will also display a thumbnail of the default ‘Featuered Image’ in the Sidebar for posts where I haven’t selected one please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(get_the_id()); ?>">
    <span class="widget-listing-thumbnail">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } else { ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/branding/tellymedia-temporary-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    ?>
    </span>
    <?php get_the_title() ? the_title() + the_subtitle('<span class="widget-subtitle">', '</span class="widget-subtitle">') : the_ID(); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: if not working yet then please provide some more information your function or your wp_query.

Comment: Sorry mAyUr, can't get that working either for some reason - same problem as before, screen just goes blank/white. I know there must be a way of doing it, but my knowledge of php is pretty much non-existent. Really appreciate your efforts though!

Comment: will you please add more info about your problem or code.

Comment: Not sure what else I can post, because those are the only bits of code I'm aware of being connected to the problem?

Comment: there is a two possibility

Comment: 1) you have some error in code or query.

2) if you are using echo statement to return value in place of store your content in variable and then return. then you have to remove white space from your code or your function.php howl file in case of echo statement.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. Looking at the rest of the code, there are references to 'echo'. The lines above the code I posted originally say: <?php echo $before_widget; ?> <?php if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?> <ul> <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?> <div class="widget-listing-panel">   They're all on separate lines though. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: yes. go through removing white space and let me know if its work.

Comment: Doing it now. Will let you know how I get on ... thanks mate.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. To be honest, I'm not really sure which bits of white space to remove (maybe I've removed too much as I guess there are suppose to be some gaps between certain bits of code like the (); ? maybe. But listen, it's probably not fair of me to expect you to spend more of your time trying to help me? Thanks for trying though.

Comment: you can send me your file at mayurdevmurari1991

Comment: for right now i am free for one hour can look into your code and help you if i can ..

Comment: Thank you. Have just emailed you. Feel really bad about wasting your time though!

Comment: there is a two meager problem on your code.
two functions are not closed.
class My_Widget_Recent_Posts extends WP_Widget {

Comment: and
function widget($args, $instance) {

Comment: these both functions are not closed.. and most probably error in your code so first proper indent your code and then check for functions and conditions and go on

Comment: other everything is fine ok ??

Comment: Thanks so much. I'l reluctant to tamper any further with the code though, as php is really not my strong point. I don't actually understand any of it, but will give it a shot. Thanks again!